# Why does the 'as' keyword work while the () cast does not

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
//always works, returning a valid object into _page
        _page = _httpContext.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;

//Fails throwing the exception : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler' to type 'System.Web.UI.Page'
        _page = (System.Web.UI.Page)_httpContext.Handler;
```

I would like to know why this happens?

EDIT:

```
                //Fixes the problem
            if(_httpContext.Handler is System.Web.UI.Page)
            _page = (System.Web.UI.Page)_httpContext.Handler;
```

If i debug the 'as' keyword statement, i never get a null reference (object always assigned properly). However the () cast creates exceptions unless it has the if statment.

EDIT: After about 15 runs through the class i was able to get a null. Seems like it took more runs to find a null compared to how fast the () cast would catch an exception.

OLD: When there is a debug at the 'as' statement every time the class runs the break point hits - never null.

When tthere is a debug in the '()' statement within the if,  every time the break point hits the cast works properly. Werid

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> //always works, returning a valid object into _page
>     _page = _httpContext.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;

This didn't technically work.  If you'll notice `_page` will be `null`. It just didn't throw an error.

The `as` operator is used to tell the application "I want you to try and convert this.  It might not, and I know this, so don't throw an exception. I'll deal with it accordingly."

The `()` conversion is used to tell the application, "This object will cast to this type.  If it doesn't something is wrong, and I need to know about it."

The difference between the two casts (and when you should use them) is when you "think" something is castable to another type and when you "know" something is castable to another type.

Here is an article by Eric Lippert on the subject (changed to his blog not re-feeded):
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx

Answer (score 7):

[From here:](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88420.aspx)

> Using the as operator differs from a
>   cast in C# in three important ways:
>
> It returns null when the variable you
>   are trying to convert is not of the
>   requested type or in it's inheritance
>   chain, instead of throwing an
>   exception.  It can only be applied to
>   reference type variables converting to
>   reference types.  Using as will not
>   perform user-defined conversions, such
>   as implicit or explicit conversion
>   operators, which casting syntax will
>   do.  There are in fact two completely
>   different operations defined in IL
>   that handle these two keywords (the
>   castclass and isinst instructions) -
>   it's not just "syntactic sugar"
>   written by C# to get this different
>   behavior. The as operator appears to
>   be slightly faster in v1.0 and v1.1 of
>   Microsoft's CLR compared to casting
>   (even in cases where there are no
>   invalid casts which would severely
>   lower casting's performance due to
>   exceptions).

Comment: But why does the cast not work? I know that the Handler is a System.Web.UI.Page. I have also googled and read what you posted. Still - sense no make.

Comment: "It can only be applied to reference type variables converting to reference types" is not actually true - the value can be of any type, and the target type can also be a nullable value types. So e.g. `(int)0 as IEquatable<int>` is valid, and in particular `(object)o as int?` is a good way to check if `o` is a boxed `int` without catching exceptions. It also lets you write things such as `(T?)x as U?`, which can be marginally useful in generic code.

Comment: @Maus it doesn't actually work. The first line will actually put `null` into _page which doesn't look like what you expected

Comment: If the cast doesn't work, then `_handler` was _not_ a `System.Web.UI.Page`. Inspect it in debugger at the point of exception and see what it _actually_ points to.

Comment: @Everyone - read edit.
@Earlz, i debugged the first line, it never gets a null.

Comment: @Earlz - my bad, after about 15 runs throught he class i was able to get a null value.

Answer (score 4):

One major difference between the as cast and the prefix cast is that the prefix cast will throw an exception while the as cast will just return null.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'as' operator, if the conversion fails, it just returns null. If you do an explicit cast, it will throw an exception if the conversion fails. In this situation, the 'as' downcasts to the proper type expected. The explicit conversion can't move up to the desired type.

As a general rule, you should always do 'as' unless you really need the explicit cast (such as when you need to convert to value types).

Comment: I'm not convinced.  I would rather do Class1 foo = (Class1)bar and get the cast exception than get a not-as-useful null exception later with foo.Property or foo.Method().  That null exception could occur anywhere outside the scope of your "as".  If I expect the code to sometimes fail, then I'll use "as" and check for null.

Comment: That's the general pattern. You convert with 'as', and then check for null.

Answer (score 0):

Using `as` TRIES to cast that object to that specific type, but returns `null` on failure instead of throwing an exception (whereas casting just throws the exception). Are you sure the one with the `as` clause is actually returning a non-null object?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing that @Tejs answer said. A failed conversion with `as` produces null.

I'm going to say different from him though and as a general rule you should always use an explicit cast. I personally had much rather get an exception right where the conversion fails rather than in another page get a (seemingly) out of nowhere null reference exception.

One good use for the `as` operator though is when converting things out of a database and not wanting to check for `System.DBNull`

```
int someint = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as int? ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As many are pointing out, the `as` operator is returning a `null` in this case, avoiding the "problem" but not really "working".

This site has a good description of the 3 differences between using `as` and casting:

http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ:_What_is_the_difference_between_using_a_cast_and_the_as_operator

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's exactly what's supposed to happen. The cast failed and threw and error because the cast wasn't valid. The `as` quietly defaults to null if the cast fails.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have noted, it boils down to the fact that **"as" will return null in the event of an invalid cast, whereas an explicit cast will throw an exception**.

The other answers have some debate over whether to lean toward one or the other.  If you are going to use "as", you need to deal at some point with the fact that it may be a null.  If you are going to use an explicit cast you have to deal with a possible exception.  Depending on the use case I lean toward one or another.

I tend to use the specific cast when I know that the cast will work but the compiler doesn't, and throwing an exception would be okay (because it is an exceptional case).  But if there is a legitimate chance that the cast will be invalid, I prefer using "as" and testing for null.  This avoids catching the exception which is uglier and makes debugging harder IMO.